# python string split with dynamic variable

Tags: python, dynamic, split

I am trying to split a string that has a date block that can changed dynamically.

```
  source = purchase_volume (as of Oct 31, 2013)>4.5</n>
  purchase_volume =source.split('purchase_volume (as of Oct 31, 2013)>')[1].split('</n>)[0]
```

The date will change, the format will not. How can I dynamically tell it to ignore the change in date but still giving me the correct split ?

Comment: Are you trying to extract the date?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `>` as separator?

```
>>> source = 'purchase_volume (as of Oct 31, 2013)>4.5</n>'
>>> source.split('>', 1)[-1].split('</n>', 1)[0]
'4.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to extract the amount with the associated date, try this:

```
>>> pttrn = re.compile('([A-Z]{3}\s+[0-9]{2},\s+[0-9]{4})\)>(\d+\.?\d+)</n>', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> d,a = re.findall(pttrn, s)[0]
>>> d
'Oct 31, 2013'
>>> a
'4.5'
```

Comment: thanks, this work, but then you still need to have the regex read the source again everytime. Wondering if there is a way to set the wild character to split for (as of as of mmm dd, yyyy)?